# Is Dropbox a good place for my shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, script

I know the "*official*" place for my own shell scripts is the `$HOME/bin` folder. But i would like to use a Dropbox folder instead and then just simply append it to my $PATH. Something like `$HOME/Dropbox/bin`. I know it works, but is it a bad idea?

Comment: There is no "official" place to keep your scripts. It's completely up to you, I keep them in `~/scripts` for example.

Comment: Ok ok... i know, hence the "*official*" way of writing it. It's pretty much a convention as far as i can tell, from researching on the web and looking into literature about the subject. No need for the -1... yeesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of *not* to do this would be if you think that Dropbox (or a potential attacker of their service, or someone who has social engineered away your password) is likely to alter your shell scripts in any way. This doesn't seem like a likely scenario to me.

It makes keeping your Dropbox password secret slightly more important.

That said, I think the more 'standard' way of achieving what you are trying to achieve is with `git` and [github](https://github.com/). That way you can share your scripts between machines, have an online backup, and you get version control thrown into the mix. You also have to manually pull the directory onto each machine, which is something of a security plus (you can get the same effect with dropbox by using a separate directory into which you copy the scripts from you dropbox directory).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't currently have enough rep points to up vote your answer, but please receive a sincere thank you from me. I do have pretty strong passwords for the service, and share your view of a git centered workflow. Will definitely be checking into that.

Answer (score 1):

Considering how important the **security** of your shell scripts are to the security of your machine (especially if you run them as root) and your privacy (if you run them with your desktop user) I'd take a couple precautions with *any* third party service:

- **Don't auto-update** the files. Auto-updating means that you won't notice anything if someone introduces a change unknown to you.
- **Version control the files** using small commits and meaningful commit messages. This is probably the strongest argument to *not* use a file-centered service like Dropbox. With a history it is much easier to review the changes after manually updating your local copy.
- Use any additional **security features** available. Three-factor authentication and private/public key authentication are rather common these days with serious players.
- If you *have* to use a **password**, make it a **generated** one and **very long**, then chuck it into a password store like KeePass or LastPass.

After using a [`git`-based setup](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/) for a few years now I can thoroughly recommend it (YMMV, YAGNI, IANAL and probably other abbreviations apply).

Comment: Note that Dropbox keeps a revision of files. Not like proper revision control, but there is.

Comment: He I0b0. Thanks a lot for your answer! I will just be using this for local development, although i do agree with you, a git-based setup would be the ideal solution.